# Return only specify object property from array of values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection is like such in Mongo.

```
{
    "_id": 123,
    version: 2,
    property: "toenail",
    options: [
        {"color": "blue", age: "15"},
        {"color": "black", age: "27"}
    ]
}, 
{
    "_id": 124,
    version: 12,
    property: "tooth",
    options: [
        {"color": "green", age: "5"},
        {"color": "yellow", age: "7"}
    ]
}, 
...
```

i.e. Each object has an array of options, where each option is an object literal.

I want to find the colour for the option where the age is "15".

I do:

```
 db.saksMongoItem.find({"options.age":"15" })
```

But this give me the entire object - some noise
To narrow the scope of what is returned I do:

```
 db.saksMongoItem.find({"options.age":"15" }, {"options.color.$":1})
```

But this give me...

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(123), "options" : [ { "color" : "blue", "age:15")]}
```

Is there any way I could just get...

```
{"color": "blue"}
```

returned

Comment: Is there something missing from the answer that does not address your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong position of the `$` operator:

```js
db.saksMongoItem.find({"options.age":"15" }, {"options.$":1})
```

If you just want the color for the specified age then you need to use the aggregation framework:

```js
db.saksMongoItem.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "options.age":"15" } },
    { "$unwind": "$options" },
    { "$match": { "options.age":"15" } },
    { "$project": {
       "_id": 0,
       "color": "$options.color"
    }}
])
```